# Indexed item from 2 tables into one column

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin, innodb

I want to restrict one column in `orders` MySQL table to primary key from **2 different tables**.

Example:
I have one table `orders`

```
|order_id|item_1     |item_2     |price|
|1       |service_id1|product_id1|10.00|
|2       |product_id1|service_id1|10.00|
```

Columns `item_1` and `item_2` are basic indexes and I want to restrict each of them to following tables:
`services`

```
|service_id |name    |price|
|service_id1|service1|5.00 |
|service_id2|service2|5.00 |
```

`products`

```
|product_id |name    |price|
|product_id1|product1|5.00 |
|product_id2|product2|5.00 |
```

Basically i just want to insert data from both `services` and `products` into one column: `orders.item_1` or `orders.item_2`. Is it possible? I added both name restrictions in phpmyadmin but it doesn't work like it suppose to work, generating error 1452. Maybe I'm overthinking and the solution is easier than I think or I just want too much from mysql.

Comment: How do you tell whether a given id is a service or a product?

Comment: the only answer i got is making ID column in `products` and `services` with prefix, eg. PR001, PR002 for products and SV001, SV002 for services, as if it's only way to identify whether id is a service or product is it still possible to do what i said?

Comment: you can't have separate type_1 and type_2 columns or something?  If you didn't have a way to tell them apart, I am confused as to how you actually use this data

Answer (score -1):

This is only a foreign key constraint

Joining both in a single column makes no sense, but is doable

what you essentially have is a bridge taböe, to join different ids from different tables. As the ids are indexed this is ver fast, especially when you are looking for few items .

in the sample you need to have in both tables a 1 to add to orders a 1 as reference, and so you always must have products and services in sync with each other

> ```
> CREATE tABLE products (product_id bigint Primary KEY auto_increment, name  VARCHAR(255),price DECIMAL (10,2))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE services (sercvice_id bigint Primary KEY auto_increment, name  VARCHAR(255),price DECIMAL (10,2))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe orders (order_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
> ,item_1    BIGINT
> , item_2 BIGINT
> , price DECIMAL(10,2)
> , 
>     CONSTRAINT FK_OrdersProducts FOREIGN KEY (item_1)
>     REFERENCES products(product_id),
>         CONSTRAINT FK_OrdersServices FOREIGN KEY (item_2)
>     REFERENCES services(sercvice_id)
>     , INDEX (item_1,item_2)
> )
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e3ca961c486d37703662006d0c65e90)*

> ```
> CREATE tABLE products (product_id bigint Primary KEY auto_increment, name  VARCHAR(255),price DECIMAL (10,2))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE services (sercvice_id bigint Primary KEY auto_increment, name  VARCHAR(255),price DECIMAL (10,2))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe orders (order_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
> ,item_1    BIGINT
> , price DECIMAL(10,2)
> , 
>     CONSTRAINT FK_OrdersProducts FOREIGN KEY (item_1)
>     REFERENCES products(product_id),
>         CONSTRAINT FK_OrdersServices FOREIGN KEY (item_1)
>     REFERENCES services(sercvice_id)
> )
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eccf7499fbcb272d28972494f59a03bd)*

Comment: but you separated products and services into different columns (products for item_1 and services for item_2), I'm asking if it possible to close services and products into one column, eg. item_1

Comment: sure you can but it makes no sense, in the sample you need to have in bith tables a 1 to add to orders a 1 as reference, and so you always must have products and services in sync with each other